# How can i use the different view modes of a mobile widget?

Tags: javascript, html, widget, mobile-phones

I'm trying to make a mobile application using the Vodafone Mobile Widget Platform and I've seen they support different view modes, like... docked, floating, etc... How can make use of them?  Also, is there any way to detect when a widget is docked or is floating?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Floating mode is supported by the Samsung H1/M1 phones, while docked mode (active icon) is supported by the runtime on the S60 phones. In order to enable these modes, add the attribute floatable="yes" and/or dockable="yes"  in your config.xml's  tag. You can detect when your widget switched modes by checking the value of widget.widgetMode inside the widgetmodechange event handler:

> widget.addEventListener('widgetmodechange',
>   callback, [true|false]);